# Get geo location from RSS feed

Tags: php

I am working on RSS feed and I want to display it on google map, for that I need geo location (latitude and longitude). Is there any way to get geolocation from RSS feed.

Please find below example link and it output the results as below:

http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss

```
[0] => Array([
        title] => With video: Marine urination outrage not stopping Afghan peace talk moves - Detroit Free Press
        [link] => http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGJ6-pSyuoJH43Om0IZipU0bYSCZg&url=http://www.freep.com/article/20120113/NEWS07/120113024/With-video-Marine-urination-outrage-not-stopping-Afghan-peace-talk-moves
        [description] =>With video: Marine urination outrage not stopping Afghan peace talk moves
        [guid] => tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=17593988265025
        [pubDate] => Fri, 13 Jan 2012 16:14:32 GMT
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: The geo location of what, exactly? There is no address in that feed, it does not refer to any specific geographic location, excpect possibly `Afgan`, which is not a place. If you actually have something to go on for a location, you can use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), but you do need to have at least a vague idea of what you want you map to display. If you want the geo-location of the server that supplied the feed you could use an IP location service to get it, but I can't really see that as being a particularly useful thing to have...

Comment: That data is not in there as far as I can see, so unless you want to spend considerable time setting up a system matching huge swaths of text against all possible locations, I'd say no...

Answer (score 0):

You could get the IP address of the feed's HTTP server, and then use geolocation library of service to get an approximate location of this IP address.

Here is a free database which can be used with many programming environments:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/city

it will return you the approximate latitude and longitude. This will be very rough. It will give you the location of the server which is serving the feed.

You can use these coordinates to display a google map.